# Java stacktrace analysis, bad header in the media?

Tags: java, stack-trace, jmf

I'm currently playing around with the JMF to get video embedded in my GUI. I got a good looking class up but I keep getting an odd stacktrace which has me scratching my head.

```
Failed to configure: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@1fc4bec
  Bad header in the media: IOException when parsing hdrl

Error: Unable to realize com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@1fc4bec
javax.media.CannotRealizeException
    at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005)
    at javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:554)
    at EmbeddedPlayer.<init>(EmbeddedPlayer.java:24)
    at MenuFrame.addMedia(MenuFrame.java:142)
    at ConfigReader.parse(ConfigReader.java:362)
    at ConfigReader.findFrames(ConfigReader.java:60)
    at ConfigReader.main(ConfigReader.java:32)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EmbeddedPlayer.<init>(EmbeddedPlayer.java:35)
    at MenuFrame.addMedia(MenuFrame.java:142)
    at ConfigReader.parse(ConfigReader.java:362)
    at ConfigReader.findFrames(ConfigReader.java:60)
    at ConfigReader.main(ConfigReader.java:32)
seek: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
```

I've only been developping in Java for a year and I'm not quite sure what the trace is telling me right now.

Any help even just telling me what's happening would help greatly.

here is EmbeddedPlayer:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class EmbeddedPlayer extends JPanel {

    private MenuFrame parent;
    public static final String DEFAULT_MEDIA_PATH = "media/";

    public EmbeddedPlayer(MenuFrame parent, String file) {
        this.parent = parent;
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);

        Player mediaPlayer = null;
        Component video = null;
        Component controls = null;
        try {
            MediaLocator location = new MediaLocator(file);
            mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(location);
            video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if ( video != null ) { add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER); }
        if ( controls != null ) { add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH); }

        this.parent.add(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Based on this example: http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/

Comment: What's the value of `file` that you pass in?

Comment: File is a string containing the complete path to my video file: file:///E:\~java\Projects\1.avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe EmbeddedPlayer is your code(not jmf), and hence you need to check which object is being referenced at EmbeddedPlayer.java, line 35. Or post the code of EmbeddedPlayer.

UPDATE: The problem seems to be unable to create playback engine.
Maybe this url will help http://blog.msbbc.co.uk/2007/06/mp3-playback-in-java.html

Comment: I added my code, but I'm using EmbeddedPlayer as a custom class which extends JPanel so I can easily place it on my frame.